# Simple if else conditions gone wrong

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

It keeps printing 'found' although there is no 'jpg 'or 'jpeg' or 'png' or 'bmp' or 'gif' in 'asduas'. What am i doing wrong? :s

```
if 'jpg 'or 'jpeg' or 'png' or 'bmp' or 'gif' in 'asduas':
    print('found')

else:
    print('not found')
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/20002503/1903116

Comment: You can try just putting all values you want to compare in a list.

    >>> if 'asduas' in ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'gif']:
    ...     print 'found'
    ... 
    
    >>> if 'jpg' in ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'gif']:
    ...     print 'found'
    ... 
    found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is for example:

```
if 'jpg' in 'asduas'  or 'jpeg' in 'asduas' or 'png' in 'asduas' or 'bmp' in 'asduas' or 'gif' in 'asduas':
    print('found')
```

Comment: please keep it pythonic :(

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
if any(x in 'asudas' for x in ('jpg','jpeg','png','bmp','gif')):
    print('Found')
```

Comment: perhaps it would be even better with `asudas.endswith(x)` since you are checking for file name extensins (most likely)

Answer (score 1):

Your if evaluates if either of the following results in `True`:

```
'jpg'
'jpeg'
'png'
'bmp'
'gif' in 'asduas'
```

Because `'jpg'` evaluates to `True` it wil enter the if always.

What you probably want

```
if any(x in 'asduas' for x in ('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'gif')):
```

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand how boolean expressions work. You are looking for:

```
if 'jpg' in 'asduas'  or 'jpeg' in 'asduas' or 'png' in 'asduas' or 'bmp' in 'asduas' or 'gif' in 'asduas':
    print('found')

else:
    print('not found')
```

You can even shorten it:

```
if any(x in 'asduas' for x in ('jpg','jpeg','png','bmp','gif')):
    print('found')

else:
    print('not found')
```

Because `jpg` gives `True` the if statement will always return true.

Comment: `if {jpg, jpeg, png, bmp, gif} in 'asduas'` doesn't make sense.